# Python Syntax error using protocols

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

This is the code

```
req =   "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n" + \
        "Foo: " + \
        "A" * 530 + \
        "\r\n"
```

This is the error

```
 File "exploit-2b.py", line 34
        "A" * 530 + \
                     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

I'm sorry, I just don't know much of python, what's going on here?

**edit 1: woops, forgot the error message!**

Comment: I do not get any error in Python 3.4 or Python 2.6 .

Comment: I don't get any errors either.

Comment: I think my code is not in the mood to compute today

Comment: Post the other 30-odd lines?

Comment: Unexpected character after trailing slash + you cannot see it = trailing whitespace. Turn whatever feature on in your IDE so you can see it. (e.g., vim `set list`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you have a space after the backslash.  Set your editor to show you whitespace.